# stripe paymentRequest with total amount 0$

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

when I'm trying to make payment with payment request button I need to set 0$ amount when creating payment intent for it, but I can't, cause for creating payment intent stripe requires min 0.50$. I need it cause I'm using it for metered subscription type and don't have to charge client when subscribing. I found solution to refund after successfully subscription, but I don't like it.
I'm creating payment_intent with this api

```
app.post('/api/client-secret', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { currency, amount } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount,
      currency: 'usd',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
    });
  
    res.json({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error1", error)
  }
});
```

maybe there is other way or method to create client_secret for stripe.paymentRequest()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [payment_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents) object has a field called [`capture_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-capture_method). You can set this `manual`, in which case the payment is not immediately captured by stripe. Pay attention to the parenthesis:

(*Not all payment methods support this*)

---

On a different note, if this is a subscription, then why not use the [`subscription`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions) api or even better, [`sessions`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions). I suggest sessions because it handles all sorts of issues that may arise during a transaction, and all you need to do is wait for the [session to complete](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed), and everything will be taken care of.

Also note that the [`price`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create) object (which represents the items you are selling) comes with a field called [`usage_type`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/create#create_price-recurring-usage_type) which allows you specify that the item is *metered*, so stripe can handle the billing for you if someone purchases that item.

The stripe api is vast and well documented, so I hope this answer helps you discover a solution quickly.

Comment: thank you for responding. I'm using subscription api and I've found where I was wrong. When I've created paymentRequest I'm making confirmCardPayment() and then creating subscription, but I don't need confirmCardPayment at all. I've took it from one example and didn't realised that I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not charging the user upfront, you should use SetupIntents to save and attach card details to the Customer for charging them in the future — when they’re offline : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse